# Calling a Python Function (geopy.distance.great_circle()) with multiple dynamic tuples in arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, args, geopy

I've a List of Tuples which is created dynamically and hence, its length can vary. An example of this list is:-

`mylist=[(18.521428, 73.8544541), (28.6517178, 77.2219388), (18.9387711, 72.8353355)]`

Now, I need to call the `great_circle()` of `geopy.distance`, in such a way that I should pass all my tuples as the parameters.
Something like this-

`great_circle((18.521428, 73.8544541), (28.6517178, 77.2219388), (18.9387711, 72.8353355))`

But unable to do so, because the function `great_circle(*args, **kwargs)` is expecting individual tuples instead of a list of tuples. It is raising following exception:-

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'`

So, can you suggest how it can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line, as long as you are sure that your `list` contains **exactly** the same amount of input as required. Just do:

```py
great_circle(*mylist)
```

The `*` Operator will extract your data from the list, which will be equivalent to what you want.

Hope this helps.